# Can I specify the revision to checkout in a TeamCity build?

Tags: svn, teamcity

Is there a way to specify which SVN revision to checkout in a TeamCity build?

If I attempt to change the SVN URL to include the revision using the @ notation, eg.

svn+ssh://svn/some/url@1234

then I get an error ("Unknown path kind").

I've searched all TeamCity documentation and can find nothing appropriate.

The background to this question is that I would like to run tests on a particular revision that for some reason was not done in the past (eg. the URL was not in TeamCity at the time).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, just hit the ellipses next to the "Run" button to trigger a [custom build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Triggering+a+Custom+Build) and choose the revision from the "Last change to include" list in the resultant screen. BUT - you can only choose from revisions which the build has previously run.

Unfortunately the only other option is to create a separate VCS root against a tag of the revision you want to run to do this. Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: My main use case is to run something that has NOT previously run! :)

Comment: Unfortunately you need to create a separate VCS root against a tag of the revision you want to run to do this. Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: OK, if you add your comment into your answer I'll reluctantly mark it as the correct answer! :)

Comment: What about doing so programmaticly? How would you tell Build B to build the source revision that was last successful for Build A? I don't see an option for this. Thx.

Comment: You can also edit your VCS setting to point to the tag, build, then change it back after. Saves creating a new VCS ROOT.

Comment: @JamesC this is what I have always done, but today I realized that when I want to get the revision number of the associated tag, I get the head revision, and not the last-changed revision.  Have you seen this behavior before, and is it expected?

Answer (score 2):

For git, there is this solution. I'm not sure how it will work for svn.

There is a way to have TeamCity **list all branches** in the 'custom build' dialog (the one you open by clicking the elipsis ... next to the Run button), including ones that **haven't been built yet**.

To show the branches, go to your VCS root, and set a **branch specification**. For git, it will be something like:

```
+:refs/heads/*
```

The star `*` here is a placeholder for what to show in the branches dropdown.

Note that this may cause your configurations to build on all branches automatically - so you may want to update the build triggers.

See [the docs about feature branches](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches) for more.

Comment: Recent changes dialog did not appear without specifying that. Thanks!